# Use Handler.post() to update ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, handler

I have a `listView` and i use `ArrayAdapter.addAll` to load the data.I want to use `ListView.getChild(0)` after use `ArrayAdapter.addAll` at once.But `NullPointerException` was thrown.

I try to add the `ListView.getChild(0)` to the `MessageQueue` by using Handler.post.The app works sometimes since as I do this, but sometimes the `NullPointerException` also was thrown.

**My Code:**

```
mRightAdapter.addAll(mRightDisplayDatas); 
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() { 
    ((TextView) mLeftListView.getChildAt(0)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_right, mContext.getTheme()), null);
   }
});
```

log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.buledon.volunteerapp, PID: 4787
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.buledon.volunteerapp.widget.CitySelectView$3.run(CitySelectView.java:130)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5669)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: please show related code along with query will give better understading

Comment: Please share your stacktrace if you have an NPE

Comment: Can we see your xml layout code that you inflating in your adapter getView() method? I think you shouldn't cast your view into TextView

Comment: I didn't use getView(), I just use the original ArrayAdapter

Comment: the item is a TextView

Comment: Check if getChildAt() returns null before trying to manipulate it.

Comment: Do you have scrollview, because as I understand getChildAt returns the child from the visible elements in listview. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318862/sometimes-listview-getchildatint-index-returns-null-android) ,  [Also this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children)

Comment: So maybe you can try to use `mRightAdapter.getItem(0)` instead of `mLeftListView.getChildAt(0)`

Comment: mRightAdapter.getItem(0) can not return the view, it return the genericity Object

Comment: Use mLeftListView.post instead of mHandler.post

Comment: Yes you are right, so it seems the safe way is implementing `getView()` method as @chejaras said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also use mRightAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged. Also added values don't get  reflected in listview immediately. Use mHandler.postDelayed and add a delay of few millisecond. You can check if getChild(0) is not null. If its null post the handler again.

A cleaner way would be to add this code in getView() method of Adapter class and check for index of the view being requested. If its 0 then execute your code. This way you will be doing your stuff at right place and right time.