# Custom Listview View NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview, view, viewgroup

I have a Custom SimpleCursor listView and Chronometer. I try to do When `Chronometer`(timer ) is 00:10 Draw color a row  but its throw NullPointerException.

Thank U for Helps
Here is Code:

```
public class ListViewcursorActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Chronometer timer;
ListView lvItems;
SimpleCursorAdapter colours;
private testDBAdapter thisTestDBAdapter;
LinearLayout[] Row;
View[] v;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    thisTestDBAdapter = new testDBAdapter(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lvItems =getListView();fillData();

    timer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

    timer.setBase(android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    timer.start();

     Row =new LinearLayout[lvItems.getCount()];
     v = new View[lvItems.getCount()];
    for(int i=0;i<lvItems.getChildCount();i++) {
        v[i] =lvItems.getChildAt(i);
        Row[i] = (LinearLayout)v[i].getParent();    
    }
    timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {

        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=0;i<lvItems.getChildCount();i++){

            //  TextView child =(TextView)Row[i].getChildAt(0);
                if(  chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Timer: 00:10")){

                    try {
                        Row[1].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(ListViewcursorActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
    }
    });
}
```

Problem is : // TextView child =(TextView)Row[i].getChildAt(0);
and Row[1].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

```
    06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at net.deneme.cursorlist.ListViewcursorActivity$1.onChronometerTick(ListViewcursorActivity.java:91)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.widget.Chronometer.dispatchChronometerTick(Chronometer.java:276)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.widget.Chronometer$1.handleMessage(Chronometer.java:268)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-02 17:00:57.263: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 17:00:57.273: I/dalvikvm(869): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-02 17:00:57.273: E/dalvikvm(869): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: which line you are getting the null pointer exception....... log cat please ........

Comment: problems are : TextView child =(TextView)Row[i].getChildAt(0); and Row[1].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Comment: and I want to ask either child is null or Row[i] is null.......

Comment: I just try , it is Row[i]; Row[i] is null it thorws Null pointer Exception

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children

Comment: can you explain wt you are doing in the first for loop? why?

Comment: first loop : I try get all Rows from Listview as View. And then second loop when chronometer is 00:10 , draw color.blue any (1) row.
But Row throws nullPointerException

Comment: @DheereshSingh nope it isn't about  int i = 0; i <= f_listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - f_listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++)
 Thanks for help

Comment: @DheereshSingh I try to I cannot get Views, lvItems.getChildAt(i) sends me null How can I get view.

Comment: http://gettingintomobile.blogspot.in/2011/07/listview-highlight-fix-for-android-bug.html looks no need to get (LinearLayout)v[i].getParent();

Comment: but still think if you have more element then fit to screen you would get some children null.........

Comment: my listview looks like here: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

lvItems.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null) don't send  null but it isn't working to getview

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView child =(TextView) Row[i].getChildAt(0);
```

why not get it by id?

```
LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) Row[i];
if(row != null) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewBy(R.id.textviewid);
    if(TextView != null)
       //do stuff
}
```

Does that help?

Also look more into code what is Row? a Linearlayout right? it is kind of unclear code. Maybe organize a bit better.

Comment: I cannot use R.id.bla.. Because I use Dynamic cursor List View ;
Like here : http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Answer (score 0):

Null Pointer Exception usually means that you are trying to access something which does not exist in the current context.

Verify that your XML is correctly referred in the Java code.

Comment: well sorry I cannot add xml file . But I am sure it isn't about xml file thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the adapter being set to the listview anywhere in your `onCreate`. Set the adapter and see if it fixes the problem. Items will be created and they will have parents once you set the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

For nullpointer exception you can use the debugging to trace the nullpointer exception it can tell you where the nullpointer exception occur.

Comment: okey , I got why I gets null,it is lvItems.getChildAt(i) it sends me null. but how can ı get childs?