# How to know if list view is scrollable programatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am copying my question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173369/how-to-check-if-a-my-listview-has-scrollable-number-of-items) as it is the same question but for flutter

> How do you know if your ListView has enough number of items so that it
> can scroll?
>
> For instance, If I have 5 items on my ListView all of it will be
> displayed on a single screen. But if I have 7 or more, my ListView
> begins to scroll. How do I know if my List can scroll
> programmatically?

Thank you

I am adding the code I tried, in which I test if the controller is attached, to be able to get the position. I couldn't get the position because the controller is not attached until you actually scroll

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  _afterBuild();
  ListView.builder(
    controller: controller,
    // ...
  )    
}

Future<void> _afterBuild () async {
    if (controller.hasClients) {
      print("controller.hasClients");
      // here I would be able to get the position
    } else {
      print("controller.has no Clients");
    }       
  }
```

---

Edit: For anyone coming here: The controller was not being attached because I had a condition under which to build the ListView

So I combined the comments with the accepted answer (which is actually the answer for the question) and solved it like this (with some pseudocode):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (not loaded results from api) {
    return Something()
  } else {
    Future(_afterBuild);
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      // ...
    )
  }          
}

Future<void> _afterBuild () async {   
  if (controller.hasClients) {   
    if(controller.position.maxScrollExtent > 0){
      print('it can be scrolled');
    }
  } else {
    print("controller has no client");
  }            
}
```

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/position.html

Comment: @pskink I don't think that will work, the controller does not get attached unless you scroll. So if I have a long list that overflows, but I don't actually scroll, there is no position, as for what I understand

Comment: where have you read it is lazily attached? try to attach the same controller to two `ListView`s and you will get arror saying that the same controller cannot be attached to multiple lists - it means that it is attached right now

Comment: @pskink I have tested in my code with controller.hasClients

Comment: call it inside `Future(() {....})` callback - i mean inside `....`

Comment: Yes @pskink that is what I did, it does not get attached until you scroll

Comment: @pskink I added some code

Comment: in other words: instead `_afterBuild();` call `Future(_afterBuild);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's quite easy to do in Flutter. You should have a `ScrollController` attached to your `ListView` and then you can check the `maxScrollExtent`. If it's bigger than zero then your `ListView` can be scrolled. It also works for any scrolling view which uses `ScrollController`.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    if(controller.position.maxScrollExtent > 0){
      print('it can be scrolled');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The cotroller does not get attached until you actually scroll, that is why this doesn't work. I tried it

Comment: I've tested it and it's working. controller is getting attached immediately after build function called. maybe you're doing this before the build function being finished. that's why I used post frame callback @user3808307

Comment: I get Assertion failed: .
_positions.isNotEmpty
"ScrollController not attached to any scroll views." (I addes ome code above to the question)

Comment: It's weird. Can you provide a gist containing complete code of your widget? @user3808307

Comment: sorry, I can't do it on initState (I didn't see it was on init state), because I have to wait to load data from the api

Comment: So where exactly you're adding post frame callback? @user3808307

Comment: I think I see the problem, the ListView is only being render under the condition that there is a response from the api, that is why is not being attached. Thank you, I'll try again changing my code to attach after load from api and it will work

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked I would appreciate a positive vote on my answer ;) @user3808307

Comment: I haven't been able to yet, I will let you know

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - Assign a `GlobalKey`

`GlobalKey myKey= GlobalKey();`

Step 2 - Assign key to ListView

```js
ListView(
    key: myKey,
    ...
)
```

Step 3 - In your function that checks if the ListView is scrollable, use the following code-

```js
final RenderBox renderBoxRed = myKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
final height = renderBoxRed.size.height; // find height of ListView

if (height > MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) { // checking if listview height is greater than page height
  print("ListView is SCROLLABLE !!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like where most of the rest of the answers are going, but they aren't getting the data the most succinctly or reliably.  What you want to do is, yes, attach a `ScrollController`, and then look for the `.position` on that (which may throw if there's no single attached position). Then, ask the position for `extentAfter` and `extentBefore`, and you'll discover how much virtual view (in pixels) there is after and before the current visible portion.  If those are 0, no scrolling.  No need to figure out the size of the screen or the containers.  Flutter already knows all that when it laid everything out!

Comment: I have an app where I want to show a "scroll for more..." pop-up info at the bottom, but it does it only when extentAfter > 0.  One number to check.  And it disappears when they're scrolled to the bottom, because there is no more. :)