# How to get Listview all sub views(visible and invisible)

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

my problem is similar to [How to get all children (visible and invisible) from a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950776/how-to-get-all-children-visible-and-invisible-from-a-listview)

i need to save all listview items to bitmap, listview item is inflated by textview. whatever they are visible or invisible in the lisview.

i want to get all child views and convert to bitmap,  i tried as below:

```
view = adapter.getView(i,null,lv);
view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
         MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth()
            view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.translate(10, 10);
view.draw(canvas);

mybitmap = combineImages(mybitmap, bitmap);
```

but if item text is too much (some of them contain long text) the methods ,view.getMeasuredWidth() and view.getMeasuredHeight(), which are not working properly.

I`m wondering if my idea to this problem is right , if not , how can I solve it ?

Comment: you can use `getCount()` of the adapter.

Comment: yes I did, in my code variable 'i' is in the for statement, where 'i' loop to adapter.getCount()

Answer (score 0):

Used the following to fix:

```
 view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lv.getWidth(),
    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
        MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
```