# Get all ListView items(rows)

Tags: android, android-listview

How may I get all children of an item of `ListView` ?
There are methods to get child at position but I was not able to find any method which returns collection of all children in an item of `ListView`.

**Update** : I just found out that I need `ListView` items(rows) instead. How may I achieve this ?
What I am doing is, comparing the selected `ListView` item with all items.

Comment: Not entirely sure why you are doing this, but wouldn't it be better to just pull all the data direct from the Adapter? Instead of pulling views from the ListView.

Answer (score 7):

You get all list item from list adapter through iteration as below

```
for (int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
     adapter.getItem(i);
}
```

**Update** : You can compare specific item using index with list adapter all items as below :

```
for (int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
    if(adapter.get(selectedIndex)==adapter.getItem(i)){
       // TODO : write code here item match 
       break; // after match is good practice to break loop instead compare rest of item even match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this method to get all insight and out-sight view of list view:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < listView.getCount() ; i++){
    View v = getViewByPosition(i,listView);
}

public View getViewByPosition(int position, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition =firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(position, listView.getChildAt(position), listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess if your items in the `ListView` are of type `ViewGroup` you could do the following

```
ArrayList<View> children = new ArrayList<View>();
for (int i = item.getChildCount() - 1 ; i>=0; i--) {
    children.add(item.getChildAt(i));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a bug where `item.getChildCount() < adapter.getCount()`. I need to grab one item and color its background, and `getChildAt` apparently only returns visible children, if there are too many items

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for something like this. You need to have access to the **rootView** from which you can get the child views. **onItemSelected** is only used as it gives the rootview of clicked position.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
ImageView imgView = view.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);//your imageview that is inflated inside getView() of adapter
//similarly for other views 
}
```