# How to Add all items from a ListViewto a List<string> - Android C#

Tags: c#, android, list, listview, foreach

I am trying to add to Add all the items in my `ListView`, to a `List<string>`.

I am currently using a `foreach` loop.

Code:

```
 private void lvNotes_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //Where I want the Line to be deleted!
            List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
            string line;
            foreach(line in notesList.Items)
            {
                stringList.Add(line);
            }
```

But I am getting an error on the `.Items` part of the `foreach(line in listview1.Items)` loop.

Why would this be?

**Update 1:**
[image: error]

**Update 2:**

[image]

I still get errors even for the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply convert listview items to strings. Each item is a [`ListViewItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

To fix your code, you'd need to use the [`.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property on a listviewitem:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
foreach(var line in listview1.Items)
{
    stringList.Add(line.Text);
}
```

Or simply use LINQ:

```
var stringList = listView1.Items.Select(i => i.Text).ToList();
```

Comment: Where is `notesList` coming from?

Comment: This is for android, not WinForms, so listview1.Items gives an error

Comment: You never defined `notesList` anywhere. You never mentioned it in your original question. I don't even know what it is...

Comment: `notesList` is listview1, just renamed to understand easier, I have changed it in original Question.

Comment: If you're going to use linq, be sure to include it at the top: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Please see Update 2

Comment: I'd have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821744/get-all-listview-itemsrows). One of these solutions may help you out.