# onClick of an Imageview which is an item of a Listview, in custom adapter's onClick() method, i want to get all rows of Listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have a Listview in which there is an imageview as an item. I have used custom adapter for listview. When I click on the Imageview of an item in listview, it takes me to the onClick method inside Custom adapter. In that onClick() method, all I want is to get entire Listview so that I can fade out rest of the list rows except the clicked one. I tried lots of answer from StackOverflow but none worked for me. please help.

Here is the onClick() method in Custom adapter

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
        Object object= getItem(position);
        DataModel dataModel=(DataModel)object;

        switch (v.getId())
        {
          case R.id.album_overflow:

            View myview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_scrolling,null);
            myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_scrolling,null);
            ListView listview = myview.findViewById(R.id.list_myContent);
            listView.setAdapter(this);
            int count = listView.getChildCount();
            Log.d("Adapter:onItemClick ", "listView.getChildCount : "+  listView.getChildCount());      
            break;
          }
}
```

this child count gives 0; whereas there is 25 records in list

Comment: this way i can do it in onCreate() method but thats gets fired when i click on any other place of listView other than the image view

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: You can use a recycler view instead, which is more developer-friendly and memory efficient.

As far I understood, you have to update the look and feel of items in listview in each click. That can be done using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Logic: Tag the count with each view with a boolean tag. Those with true will be enabled and with false will be faded out. Initially, all will be false. Once the user clicks an item, change that particular item tag to true, then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). It should work as expected.

Comment: this way i can in onCreate() method but not in adapter
 int count = listView.getChildCount();
 for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
 if (i == ourPos) {
 continue;
 }
 final View child = listView.getChildAt(i);
 if (child != null) {
 child.clearAnimation();
 mFadeOut.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
 mFadeOut.setDuration(10000);
 child.startAnimation(mFadeOut);

Comment: isn't there any way to get entire listview in onClick() method of custom_adapter class.

Comment: You can try this on, may be it will be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821744/get-all-listview-itemsrows