# How to set a final scroll's position in listView?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adapter

Maybe someone faced such a problem: I have adapter class, customView class. Everything works normal. But: When I scroll listView, It's possible to stop the scroll anywhere in the middle.
But I expected: a final scroll's position (when soon as user's finger is up and inertia-movement is completed)  should always be like on my screenshot(image1) and never like this(image2).
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right.

To achieve this in `ListView` [Android ListView - stop scrolling at 'whole' row position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338509/android-listview-stop-scrolling-at-whole-row-position)

For `RecyclerView` You can achieve this by using [SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SnapHelper)

```
LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

Comment: #shb, hello. Thank you for advice. After studying the information that you advised I came to a decision: (maybe someone will be useful):

Comment: #shb, hello. Thank you  for your advice.  After studying the information what you advised, it seems I found solving problem for me:(maybe it will be useful for someone):

Comment: View childView = view.getChildAt(0);
                Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, childView.getWidth(), childView.getHeight());
                double height = childView.getHeight();
                view.getChildVisibleRect(childView, rect, null);
                if (Math.abs(rect.height()) < height / 2.0) {
                    view.smoothScrollToPosition(view.getLastVisiblePosition());
                } else {
                    view.smoothScrollToPosition(view.getFirstVisiblePosition());