# Android list view returns null value for getChildAt()

Tags: android, listview, get-childitem

Hi I am developing small android application in which I want to get child at particular position in my list view.But it gives null value for me. My list and data provided to list view is proper because its working fine. But I am not able to get child at element. I did this in following way:

```
// inside oncreate of listactivity .... 
setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, getData(path),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "title" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    ListView listview = getListView();

    listview.setSelection(20);
    View view = listview.getChildAt(3);
```

But it gives me null value. I think I am trying to get that value before it get displayed. how to do this? Am I doing something wrong? Need Help. thank you

Comment: because it hasn't been created yet. why do you need that?

Comment: @njzk2 thank you for replay. What actually I want when i display my list i m doing setSelection(). So i want to know actually how much scroll occurred. So but getting that element i can find getchildat().gettop(). Thats why i want that. Any solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView getChildAt returning null for visible children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get position of the selected child position in pixels relative the top of the ListView:
    listview.getSelectedView().getTop()
But this will not gives you how much scroll occured, only how much pixels you have from top of selected item to the top of ListView.