# Nullpointerexception while updating UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-checkbox

I'm reading some records from database and loading them in `ListView`. The `ListView` consist `CheckBox` and `TextView`. Loading is done over `AsyncTask`. This part of application works fine.

The next step is automatically checking some checkboxes according to some flags from database and here I get problem. I'm trying to check those items inside `onPostExecute()` and then I get error about `NullPointerException`. If I do same from, for example, `setOnClickListener()` of button widget than it works fine.

The question is how to check if `ListView` is populated, are checkboxes and `TextView` loaded and visible on screen?

I don't know if it will help the part of code where program breaks looks like:

```
        for (j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)listView.getChildAt(j); // Find by under LinearLayout
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.ColChk);

        for (k=0; k<rbmjere.size(); k++)
        {
            if (checkbox.getTag().toString() == rbmjere.get(k).toString())
            {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);

            }
        }   
    }
```

It breaks on that line:

```
LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)listView.getChildAt(j);
```

I must mention that this works only if I manually press on button which runs code for automatic checking the boxes and this works only when all data is loaded.

---

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spckontrola_update);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    btnPohrani = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPohrani);

    btnProvjeri = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnProvjeri);

    btnProvjeri.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new loadSPCKontrole().execute("FCN");
        }
    });
MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public void fillData()
{                       
    SimpleAdapter listadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, MyArrList, R.layout.activity_list_row,

    new String[] {"OpisMjere", "RbMjere"}, new int[] {R.id.ColOpis, R.id.ColCode});

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);       
}

private class loadSPCKontrole extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{                   

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SPCUpdate.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading in progress ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        HashMap<String, String> map;

        String k = params[0].toString();
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sIDKategorija", k));

        try
        {                       
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.16.48" + "/spc/get_spcmjere.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+ e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
               sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

               String line="0";
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                              sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        int ct_id;
        String ct_name;

        try
        {

              jArray = new JSONArray(result);
              JSONObject json_data=null;
              for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                     json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     ct_id=json_data.getInt("RbMjere");
                     ct_name=json_data.getString("OpisMjere");

                     map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     map.put("RbMjere", String.valueOf(ct_id));
                     map.put("OpisMjere", ct_name);

                     MyArrList.add(map);
                 }                    

         }
        catch(JSONException e1)
        {
            Log.e("Greška konvertiranja", e1.toString());
        } 
        catch (ParseException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        fillData();

        listView.setAdapter(new SPCMjereAdapter(SPCUpdate.this));

        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}

   public class SPCMjereAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Context context;

        public SPCMjereAdapter(Context c) 
        {           
            context = c;                    
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return MyArrList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_row, null); 

            }

            // ColID
            TextView txtOpis = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColOpis); 
            txtOpis.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("OpisMjere") +".");

            // ColCode
            TextView txtRbMjere = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColCode);
            txtRbMjere.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("RbMjere"));


            // ColChk               
            CheckBox Chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColChk);
            Chk.setTag(MyArrList.get(position).get("RbMjere"));

            return convertView;

        }

    }
```

And here is code how I get items that should be checked:

```
DB objDB = new DB();
    ArrayList<Integer> rbmjere = objDB.getCheckedSPC(ID);

    int k=0;
    int j=0;
    for (j=0; j<MyArrList.size(); j++)
    {

        LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)listView.getChildAt(j); // Find by under LinearLayout
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.ColChk);

        for (k=0; k<rbmjere.size(); k++)
        {
            if (checkbox.getTag().toString() == rbmjere.get(k).toString())
            {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
            }
        }   
    }
```

This code above works only when listview is populated with items and if this code is under OnClickListener() but it doesn't work if I run it from onPostExecute because it seems that all rows in listview are not loaded. So my question is what should I do to get information when is loading of all rows finished and after that check which items should be checked according to data that i get from database?

Comment: Well show us the code where you initialize listView

Comment: you should not use your listview like that. use the listadapter of choice to maintain your db data (e.g cursor adapter) and flag/unflag/setText etc based on that inside your adapters getView

Answer (score 1):

Because of view recycling, listView.getChildAt() will only return a view for the positions it is displaying, not severals.

you can check this other question here. it has the answer you are looking for:
[ListView getChildAt returning null for visible children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children)

Answer (score 1):

In your case I think that piece of code should be inside your adapter's getView implementation.

Here you go with examples on

- [SimpleCursorAdapters](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)
- [CustomCursorAdapters](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/)

And how to use them with your List.

Comment: here, have an example of how to use [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) and [CustomCursorAdapter](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/) - to shy to edit it directly into jfs' answer :-o

Answer (score 0):

First of all you know when the list is loaded by reading the number of items in your data set and if the listview's data set is equal to that, then all the data is loaded on the listview.. unfortunately I can't help you more with this as I can't see your data load code here..

Second, you should change:

```
for (j=0; j<3; j++)
```

**with**

```
int listChildSize = listView.getChildCount();
for (j = 0; j < listChildSize ; j++)
```

**EDIT**

jfs is right, you should add:

```
if (checkbox.getTag().toString() == rbmjere.get(k).toString())
            {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);

            }
```

In a custom Adapter. 
[Here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2012/07/android-listview-tutorial.html) is a sample of custom adapter and also ViewHolder pattern.