# Listview not behaving as expected

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an activity in which I play media in the background, I have a listview in which I have rows specific to lyrics, the whole lyrics is in an array. Now I want that when the media player reaches a specific time, the related lyrics (Row) be scrolled to the center of the listview and this row be highlighted in a different shade. For this I use smoothScrollto() function inside the getview method. However once the if else conditions execute my list scrolls up and down in an erratic fashion and its repetitive so much so that it is unreadable. Below is my code:

**Class level Variables:**

```
String [] LyricsE; 
String [] LyricsH; 
ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter dataAdapter;
```

**onCreate:**

```
dataAdapter = new arrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, LyricsH);

listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

**Custom Class:**

```
public class arrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] lyrics;
        public arrayAdapter(Context context, String[]lyrics ) {
            super(context, R.layout.list);
            this.context = context;
            this.lyrics = lyrics; 

        }
        public int getCount() {
            return lyrics.length;

        }

        public String[] getItem(int position) {

            return (lyrics);
        }


        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



            if (convertView == null) { 
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false); 
            }
            TextView textView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2));
            textView.setText(lyrics[position]);



            if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 > 0 && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 < 20){
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(3);
                System.out.println("FIrst if");
            }else if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 > 20 && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 < 54){
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(4);
                System.out.println("2 if");
            }else if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 > 54 && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 < 67){
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(5);
                System.out.println("3 if");
            }else if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 > 67 && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 < 75){
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(6);
                System.out.println("4 if");
            }else if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 > 20 && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 < 54){
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(7);
                System.out.println("5 if");
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, why do you have your media player's current position conditions inside `getView()` method? It can't work as `getView()` is called only when `ListView` refreshes its elements.

Comment: I had earlier implemented a handler to check the media player progress and accordingly scroll the rows in the listview. But now as I want a different shade too for one particular row I have to manuplate this inside the get view method. This is a very important point, I had watched Romain guy warn about the same but somehow forgot it. Thanks a lot to remind me of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get your conditions out of `getView()` method, it's not the right place for them.

You have mentioned that you have a handler which polls media player about its current state frequently. Use it - it's the right way to go.

You also said, that you need it to be inside `getView()` because you want your 'selected' row to change its background. That's not true. You know a position to which you want to scroll, right? So you can get this specific `View` from your `ListView` and change it as you like.

Use `getChildAt()` method to get `View` at specific position. Remember that `getChildAt(0)` will return the FIRST VISIBLE element, not the first from the whole list. Here's the solution for this problem: [ListView getChildAt returning null for visible children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children)

**EDIT :**

According to second problem you mentioned - that when you change color of one element, the other one is also changing it's color. The reason for such behaviour is that `ListView`, in order to work efficiently, to create element tries to reuse other element. Most of the time it works fine, because we usually want to have the same style for all elements - this way, it doesn't have to create each element separately, but rather uses existing one instead. It happens in `getView()` method in `Adapter` and it comes as `convertView`.

Anyway, it means that you rather want to change element's style inside `getView()`, after it's already created. That also means that you need your custom adapter again. :)

I wrote a simple adapter for you:

```
public class LyricsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final static int NOT_SELECTED_ID = 0;
    private final static int SELECTED_ID = 1;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mSelectedItem;
    private int selectedItemLayoutId, unselectedItemLayoutId;

    private String [] mList;

    public LyricsAdapter(Context context, String [] lyrics) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mList = lyrics;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        boolean selected = (((LyricsAdapter)((ListView)parent).getAdapter()).getSelectedItem() == position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            if(selected) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.selected_item_layout, parent, false);
                convertView.setId(SELECTED_ID);
            } else {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.unselected_item_layout, parent, false);
                convertView.setId(NOT_SELECTED_ID);
            }
        } else {
            if(selected && (convertView.getId() == NOT_SELECTED_ID)) {      // If it's selected, but still uses not-selected layout
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.selected_item_layout, parent, false);
                convertView.setId(SELECTED_ID);
            } else if(!selected && (convertView.getId() == SELECTED_ID)) {  // If it's not selected, but still uses selected layout
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.unselected_item_layout, parent, false);
                convertView.setId(NOT_SELECTED_ID);
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mList.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int pos) {
        mSelectedItem = pos;
    }

    public int getSelectedItem() {
        return mSelectedItem;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it though, so it might have some issues. But I hope you get idea. Now basically what you want to do, is in your code, where you call:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

You also have to call:

```
// Inform adapter which item is selected
((LyricsAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).setSelectedItem(position); 

// Refresh ListView's element so that selected one will update it's layout (or in other words - call `getView()` for all items again) 
((LyricsAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
listView.refreshDrawableState();
listView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the third point you made? Specifically where do I do it?

Comment: @HereticMonk You mean that `getChildAt()` thing? In a place where you have your `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(5)` for example, and right after that, you write `View element = listView.getChildAt(5)` and you change `element`'s background. Is it clear, or not really? If not, I'll try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: It is mate, I will implement this now in two wags of a lambs tail.

Comment: Hey and thanks a ton mate, I think by making a custom adapter I did not help myself much :)

Comment: Its giving a NPE however.

Comment: No problem. What gives you NPE?

Comment: Over here: element.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

Comment: @HereticMonk Have you already solved your issue, or still need help with NPE?

Comment: No I am still getting a NPE and its boggling me! When I scroll to a position in the list say lv.SetSmoothScrollto(3) and then when I getChildAt(3) it returns null!

Comment: @HereticMonk How many elements from `ListView` are VISIBLE on a screen?

Comment: Only one in this case. I am confused should I do getChildAt(0) for the top element which I have scrolled to top programitically using SetSmoothScrollTo(3) or is there a different way?

Comment: Also I have one more problem now, the listview rows are colored randomly, when I set a background to first row some row at the bottom gets colored too!

Comment: Indeed, that's your problem. See, I told you to be aware of this by giving you this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children

It's quite common issue, because when you use `getChildAt(int position)` method, the position you specify is not the position in container you provide to `ListView`, but rather position on the screen. So yes, it will also differ between different screen sizes. I think it's quite well explain in a link I gave.

Comment: @HereticMonk According to second problem, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Also I would like to point out that I found it better to use lv.setSelection(x) rather than lv.SetSmoothScrollTo(x)

Comment: @HereticMonk Please, check my edited answer. According to setSmoothScrollTo() vs setSelection(), I don't really know why it's better. I have personally used setSmoothScrollTo() and it worked just fine. But you can decide yourself, it's not a big deal here now about it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`listView.smoothScrollToPosition()` etc is not `ListAdapter`'s job to decide. All such code should go inside the class that holds the `ListView` instance's reference, which is probably the Activity/Fragment class.

Comment: Agreed, that was my bad. Now let me rephrase the question.