# How to test a ListActivity with test data?

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm writing tests for a simple Android application (it's a school project) and I'm having trouble testing the activity ContactListActivity which extends Android's ListActivity.

### What I would like to test

Clicking the first item in ContactListActivity's ListView and checking if the ContactDetailActivity was started.

### Problem

The list data comes from an SQLite database. For testing, I'm loading test data into the ListView, so the test won't be working with live data. Loading the test data works fine. Watching the emulator while running the test, I can see the activity being started and the test data appearing in the list. However, trying to access the first (and only) list item fails.

### Test method

```java
@UiThreadTest
public final void testLoadContactDetail() {
    ListView list = activity.getListView();
    assertNotNull(list);

    ContactsListAdapter adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(
        getInstrumentation().getContext(),
        createData() // Creates an ArrayList of test data
    );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // list.getAdapter().getCount() is expectedly 1
    // list.getChildCount() is unexpectedly 0

    assertNotNull(list.getChildAt(0)); // Assertion fails

    // (...)
}
```

As can be seen, I'm annotating the test with `@UIThreadTest` to be able to manipulate view elements. A new ListAdapter is created with test data and set to the list. Then, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` makes sure that the list knows about the new data.

### Question

How can I load test data from within an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 into a ListView so that the data will not only be displayed on screen, but actually "be there", meaning the list item can be fetched with `list.getChildAt(0)` and be clicked?

### Entire test case

```java
public class ContactListActivityFunctionalTest extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ContactListActivity> {

    private ContactListActivity activity;

    public ContactListActivityFunctionalTest() {
        super(ContactListActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public final void testLoadContactDetail() {
        ListView list = activity.getListView();
        assertNotNull(list);

        ContactsListAdapter adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(
            getInstrumentation().getContext(),
            createData()
        );
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        assertNotNull(list.getChildAt(0));

        // Anything beyond this point is never executed,
        // because the above assertion fails, and I have no idea
        // if this test code is correct at all.

        ActivityMonitor monitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(
            ContactDetailActivity.class.getName(), null, false
        );

        TouchUtils.clickView(this, list.getChildAt(0));

        ContactDetailActivity contactDetailActivity = 
            (ContactDetailActivity)monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(2000);
        assertNotNull(contactDetailActivity);
        assertTrue(getInstrumentation().checkMonitorHit(monitor, 1));
        contactDetailActivity.finish();
    }

    private List<ContactInterface> createData() {
        ContactInterface contact = new Contact();
        contact.setId(1L);
        contact.setName("Unit Test").setPhone("0123456789").setPosition(3);
        List<ContactInterface> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactInterface>();
        contacts.add(contact);
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I've asked how to load test data from within an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, but perhaps the answer to the question is to use ActivityUnitTestCase rather than ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 in this particular case:

1. General activity behaviour is being tested, rather than interaction with other components
2. Well, it works...

Here is the rewritten, working test case that tests whether the ListView exists and whether the correct activity is started after a click on the list's first item.

```
public class ContactListActivityTest
    extends ActivityUnitTestCase<ContactListActivity> {

    private ContactListActivity activity;

    public ContactListActivityTest() {
        super(ContactListActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent(
            getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), ContactListActivity.class
        );
        startActivity(intent, null, null);
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public final void testItemClick() {
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnStart(activity);
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnResume(activity);

        // Check if list exists
        ListView list = activity.getListView();
        assertNotNull("Intent was null", list);

        // Load test data
        ContactsListAdapter adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(
            getInstrumentation().getContext(),
            createData()
        );
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        assertEquals(2, adapter.getCount());

        // Check if list has at least one item to click
        View firstItem = list.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null);
        assertNotNull(firstItem);

        // Perform a click on the first item
        list.performItemClick(
            firstItem,
            0,
            list.getAdapter().getItemId(0)
        );

        // Check if the contact details activity got started
        Intent intent = getStartedActivityIntent();
        assertNotNull(intent);
        assertEquals(
            ContactDetailActivity.class.getName(),
            intent.getComponent().getClassName()
        );
    }

    private List<ContactInterface> createData() {
        List<ContactInterface> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactInterface>();

        ContactInterface contact = new Contact();
        contact.setId(1L);
        contact.setName("Jane Doe").setPhone("0123456789").setPosition(1);
        contacts.add(contact);

        ContactInterface contact2 = new Contact();
        contact2.setId(2L);
        contact2.setName("John Doe").setPhone("0234567890").setPosition(2);
        contacts.add(contact2);

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `listView.getChildAt` method returns visible views. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767006/693752

So, my guess is that the item is not visible yet. None are as getChildCount is returning 0. Maybe you should either :

- wait a bit before asserting. Ok, it's dirty but UI testing needs it sometime.
- post the assert inside a runnable on the ui thread so that it gets executed after the listview is executed. This will turn your test into something a bit more complex as you would have to synchronize the future runnable and the current testing thread a countDownLatch. And for this, you should consider not using @UIThreadTest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I've tried waiting a couple of seconds before asserting, unfortunately to no avail. I finally caved and got myself 'Android Application Testing Guide'. Following a recipe therein, I wrote a new test case based on `ActivityUnitTestCase<T>` which works perfectly.

Comment: I never heard about this class before. Thx a lot.