# Not able to access a textview inside listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I am developing an app for Android using Eclipse.

I have a fragment that has a listview. I want to change the text of one Textview located inside one row of the listview.

```
public class FragmentShowList extends Fragment {

public FragmentShowList() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_list,
            container, false);  

    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_show);

    DBAdapter helper = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    String tableName = Tables.TABLENAME_CATEGORIES_MAIN;
    Tables table = new Tables(tableName);

    Cursor cursor = helper.getCursor(tableName);

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.row_category_color, R.id.row_category_name};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_category, cursor, 
            table.getColumns(), to, 0);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    View view = lv.getChildAt(0);
    //TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_category_name);
    //tv.setText("haha");

    return rootView;

}}
```

I'm able to create and view the list, but when I try to run the two last lines that are with the "//" the app crashes due to a "null pointer exception"

and the xml file for the rows is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_category_color"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_category_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/row_category_color"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_category_color"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

It seems that I'm not able to access to the children of the listview and I don't know why. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to understand the concept of an adapter and view reusability. What it does is mapping some data to a list of views. You can't access the individual views, but you can request for them to be recreated after the data has changed. Use the adapter method notifydatasetchanged() for that.

Comment: Your second problem is that the simplecursoradapter will not fill in the fields of your layout as it's thought as a super super light replacement for a list, but not for much use in a real app. You need to read into making your own adapters.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM the purpose of the `getChildAt` method is to get particular views within the `ListView`, its function is tangentially related to view reusability, but view reusability doesn't mean you can't get particular views.  Villoro, what does `lv.getFirstPosition()` return?

Comment: The data has not changed. What I really want is to set colors on some views inside listview. In order to do that I was trying to access a textview and change the text. If you could tell me some way to do that it will be very helpfull. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() returns 0. It helps?

Comment: @Jonathan there are only a finite number of existing views: only those that can fit in the screen. Due to view reusability you cannot get the reference to a textview inside one of those views and reliably say that will be always used for an element of the adapter.

Comment: @villoro you need to map that color with a piece of data and make the adapter create and modify the view according to that data. Again, if you're using the listview-adapter pattern you're accepting that. If you want a finite number of elements and now view reuse just put a linearlayout inside a scrollview and create a view per element..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to subclass `CursorAdaptor` and provide a custom implementation for `getView(...)`.

`getView(...)` of your custom adaptor is the place to change individual list items.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: In case somebody has the same problem I did what @JamesK said. I've implemented my own adaptor following that [link](http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html)

Answer (score 1):

The null pointer you are getting is because the listview elements accessible from getChildAt() range from firstvisible item in your listview to its last visible item currently shown in the screen. If you try to log the position variable in your getView() method you will clearly see that it is not called for all your items. As you scroll, the firstVisible item also changes and so does lastvisible item. On scrolling getView() is again called. Refer to [this answer] for more details.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children)