# view.findViewById for listview getchildAt() return nullpointer

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

This is the code i take from JSON data, i pass it to an array

```
public class CheckboxMCQ extends Fragment {

private View rootview;
private View footerView;
private View header;
private ListView questionAnswerList;
CheckboxAdapter checkboxAdapter;
ArrayList<checkboxmodel> arraystoreanswer;
ArrayList<checkboxmodel> arraytemppreselect;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkbox_mcq, container, false);

    questionAnswerList = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.question_answer_list);
    footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getParentFragment().getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null,false);
    header = ((LayoutInflater) getParentFragment().getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.header, null,false);
    questionAnswerList.addFooterView(footerView);
    questionAnswerList.addHeaderView(header);
    arraystoreanswer = new ArrayList<checkboxmodel>();
    arraytemppreselect = new ArrayList<checkboxmodel>();

    checkboxAdapter = new CheckboxAdapter(getActivity(), arraystoreanswer,CheckboxMCQ.this , ss_id);
    questionAnswerList.setAdapter(checkboxAdapter);


    return rootview;
}


/*preselect operation*/
public void preselectoperation(final String uid, final String sf_id, final String ssid, final String sqid, final String order) {

    class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject> {
        String response;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            urlLink url = new urlLink();
            JSONObject jsonObject = url.checkboxpreselectrow(uid, sf_id, ssid, sqid);
            return jsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
            try {
                response = jsonObject.getString("success");
                if (response.equals("1"))
                {
                    JSONArray job = jsonObject.getJSONArray("record");
                    for (int i = 0; i<job.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonOb = job.getJSONObject(i);
                        arraytemppreselect.add(new checkboxmodel(jsonOb.getString("ans_id")));
                    }

                    for (int i=0; i < arraystoreanswer.size(); i++){

                        for (int j=0; j < arraytemppreselect.size(); j++){
                            if((arraystoreanswer.get(i).getAnswerid().equals(arraytemppreselect.get(j).getAnswerid()))){
                                //do something for equals
                                Log.i("same value",arraystoreanswer.get(i).getAnswerid() );
//                                    Log.i("position value",""+ i );
                                changebackgroundpreselect(i+1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
}

public void changebackgroundpreselect(int position){
//            if (i == position){
    View view = questionAnswerList.getChildAt(position);
    Log.i("getChildAt",""+ position);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.answer_content);
            cb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkboxbuttonselected);
//            }
}
}
```

This is my void function, i know the main problem is here, but dunno how to solve it, the listview getview return null
the position i have get it, but return nullpointer at here:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.answer_content);
```

Sorry for my broken english, thank you
My error log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h92R0.jpg)

Comment: please add full java and error code...

Comment: @W4R10CK i have update my error log, but i think the problem is start from View view = questionAnswerList.getChildAt(position);  here

Comment: Please add full java code

Comment: Does every item in the list has the checkbox ?

Comment: @yanivtwin yup, i just want change the background only

Comment: `questionAnswerList` does not have a child at position `position`. That's why you get NPE. if `questionAnswerList` is a ListView,then it is not strange you get this error.  You need to get an idea about how does `ListView` work

Comment: I don't know why this is marked as duplicate because the scope of the error is in the ListView and Adapter recycling views understanding.
Anyway forget about getChildAt(), because hidden views are removed and recycled by adapter. Hold your views manually with `HashMap<Integer, Boolean>` for example, remove condition `if(convertView == null)` to force adapter create new view each time and reput checkbox value in getView, Listen to CheckedChange to update HashMap key (checkboxmodel.getId() or position) and value (checkbox view). See the my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50552571/5565544)

Answer (score 0):

Use the adapter to get view at position

instead of :

```
 View view = questionAnswerList.getChildAt(position);
```

if you post the full code i would help with code fix
hope it helps

Comment: my source code here

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing position i+1.
try to change `changebackgroundpreselect(i+1);` to `changebackgroundpreselect(i);`

post full code to identify exact problem

Comment: i post the source code here dy

Comment: where are you adding items to arraystoreanswer list and did you try above change?

Comment: arraystoreanswer list is just the big arraylist to check whether it is exist or not, if have same value, then run the function to change the checkbox inside questionAnswerList

Comment: ok but where are u adding items in it..and did u try replacing i+1 with i ?

Comment: emm, i skip the step dy, bcoz it is not the main problem adding items to arraystoreanswer . Yup, i have tried replace it, but still error , the purpose of i put i+1 is my listview contains list header and list footer, so that the items is count start from 1

Comment: can u post your adapter class and xml

Comment: also get idea of listView.getFirstVisiblePosition and listView.getLastVisiblePosition() from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children