# how to change specific field of listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

in my app i have a custom listview that every item of it have 3 Textview. i want to change the text of every of these textview. how can i do this?
    here is my code:

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_fragment, container, false);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));   
        ListView listview =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        txt1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String[] items = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list, R.id.textView1, items); 

         listview.setAdapter(adapter);  



        return rootView;
    }
```

and here is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well are you sure your adapter will work? because arrayadapter<String> accepts a layout file that has root element a textView...or i think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for the item in list view you want to change text of

```
View view = listview.getChildAt(index);
TextView t1 = view.findViewById(textView1);
TextView t2 = view.findViewById(textView2);
TextView t3 = view.findViewById(textView3);
t1.setText("New text 1");
t2.setText("New text 2");
t3.setText("New text 3");
```

This is a general idea. You might have to put condition about the visibility of the item you are trying to get.

This could help you [ListView getChildAt returning null for visible children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children)

Comment: getFirstVisiblePosition() method return 0 and getLastVisiblePosition() return -1 i dont know should i do!!

Comment: argument of getChildAt() should be the position of element whose value you want to change.

Comment: its return null always!