# What does getChildAt(0) return for a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I can understand that for a View such as RelativeLayout, `getChildAt(0)` would return the first child as defined in the XML but I'm really confused when it comes to ListView.

For a ListView, does it return the first child in the list? Does it return only the first fully visible child? Or does it return the first visible child regardless of whether it is fully or partially visible?

Comment: This might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children)

Comment: It'll return the first item view of the current data set associated with the adapter.

Comment: Thanks @sleeping_dragon that helped clear my confusion.

Comment: @IronBlossom I think that is incorrect according to the answer in the link provided by sleeping_dragon. ListView.getChildAt(n) can only be used for visible items.

Comment: @David Heisnam I gave it as a comment, not an answer. My bad that i waited for your response. Anyway, `int f=lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() -lv.getHeaderViewCount(); int l= lv.getLastVisiblePosition() - lv.getFooterViewCount(); if(wantedPosition>= f && wantedPosition<=l) lv.getChildAt(wantedPosition);` hope this help. ( writing from my mobile, can't actually give code snippet, sorry if there is any typos)

Comment: Thanks @IronBlossom it's clear to me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mListView.getChildAt(i) returns any (partially or fully) visible  child where, `i` can vary from `0` for the first visible child to `mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() - mLisView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` for the last visible child.