# Android TypeFace - requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I'm changing the `TypeFace` to `Bold` of a TextView in a ListView.

```
(TextView) listView.getChildAt(childIndex)).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, 1);
```

It works fine but I'm constantly getting this:

```
09-17 10:57:41.996  20991-20991/com.XXXX.XXXXX W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{22467cb8 V..D.... ........ 0,270-480,366 #1020014 android:id/text1} during second layout pass: posting in next frameX
```

I already read all other threads (hope so) concerning this issue. Most commonly this is an issue of the `fastscroll` attribute but unfortunately this hasn't solved my problem.

If I comment out the line mentioned above I'm not getting these warnings anymore but the type won't display bold...

Would be nice to find a workaround.

EDIT I:

```
 @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                getViewByPosition(mDrawerListView);
```

This is the onScroll of the ListView which calls: getViewByPosition(mDrawerListView);

```
public void getViewByPosition(ListView listView) {
        int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (listView.getChildAt(i) != null) {
                listView.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);

                if(i>0) {
                    // Typeface.DEFAULT, 0 == NORMAL
                    ((TextView) listView.getChildAt(i)).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, 0);
                }

            }

            for (int j = 0; j < HeaderArray.length; j++) {
                int childIndex = HeaderArray[j] - firstListItemPosition;

                if (listView.getChildAt(childIndex) != null) {
                    listView.getChildAt(childIndex).setEnabled(false);

                    //BUG THROUGH TYPEFACE.BOLD
                    //requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{
                    // Typeface.DEFAULT, 1 == BOLD
                    ((TextView) listView.getChildAt(childIndex)).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, 1);
                    // listView.getChildAt(childIndex).setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                }
            }
            listView.refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }
```

Solution:
I moved the getViewByPosition() to getView and now the message doesn't appear anymore. Additionally I had to adjust the method so that I don't use the listView.getChildAt(pos) anymore.

```
public void getViewByPosition(ListView listView, View v, int position) {
    v.setEnabled(true);
    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, 0);

    for (int j = 0; j < HeaderArray.length; j++) {
        if(HeaderArray[j]==position+1){
            v.setEnabled(false);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, 1);
        }
    }
    listView.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

Comment: when/where do you call `setTypeface` ?

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks

Comment: you should do that in `getView` method, no need for `onScroll`

Comment: You're right that the problem disappears but I had to call getViewByPosition in the onScroll because I set the background color depending on enabled true or false. When I move the getViewByPosition to getView it only sets the list item to enabled=false when completely visible. So when it is half visible the background color and the typeFace of this item isn't adjusted.

Comment: no: getView is called right after your item starts appearing, not when it is completly visible

Comment: So there must be something wrong in the getViewByPosition method? I also use a headerimage so perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6766945/982366 -> That's the problem. Half visible items are not considered in the getView. So it is no solution to call getViewByPosition in getView. My solution works great except this nasty message that is thrown...

Comment: then call `Log.d` in `Adapter#getView` and slowly scroll your list view and you will see when it is called, you should really do all View related stuff (setting text of TextViews, setting the backgrounds, fonts etc etc)  in `getView()` method

Comment: I'm calling listView.setEnabled(false) to set the background via an xml state. The bold typeface is added in the getViewByPosition(). To be able to call setEnabled and setTypeface in the getView I have to change my logic. In the HeaderArray are all positions in the listView which should be set to setEnabled(false) and typeFace.bold. Best way would be to adjust the list one time and it is baked but I can't imagine how this should work?

Comment: so you have `position` parameter in `getView` method, just use it

Comment: @pskink Thanks for pushing me into the right direction. I updated the question with my solution. So the listView.getChildAt was very confusing...I shouldn't have discovered it :D

Comment: that's great that it worked...