# Check all checkboxes in a listview when one is clicked

Tags: java, android

I have a `listview` whereby each `listview`item has a checkbox that the user can select an item with. I also have a `checkbox` above the `listview`which is expected to automatically check all the checkboxes in my list when clicked.
I am having problems implementing the appropriate for this. Any ideas?

```
public class NotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CheckBox universalCheckBox;
    private ListView mListNotes;
    NoteListAdapter na;
    private boolean isAnyItemChecked = false;
   private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
        mListNotes = findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
        // handling long click for list view item
         mListNotes.setLongClickable(true);
        mListNotes.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                for (int index = 0; index < parent.getChildCount(); ++index) {
                    View nextChild = (parent.getChildAt(index));
                     mCheckBox = nextChild.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    universalCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                isAnyItemChecked = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
        universalCheckBoxLogic();
    }

    private void universalCheckBoxLogic() {
        universalCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             mCheckBox.setChecked(true); // this not working for me

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: i need to get the right reference of my listview checkbox item from setOnCheckedChangeListener so i can check all the boxes from there

Comment: `i need to get the right reference of my listview checkbox item ` ??? There are so many items. About which one are you talking? If you want to check all checkboxes for all items then you do not need refrences to items. Not even to one.

Comment: That code is no good. You should have realised already that things should be done differently. If you check a checkbox of an item. Then scroll the item out of sight and come back. Then is the checkbox still checked?

Comment: Besides the checkbox what do items contain more?

Comment: `mCheckBox.setChecked(true); // this not working for me` Why not? Doesn't it become checked? And why do you have a `universalCheckBox` AND a `mCheckBox` ? For what?

Comment: this is actually a notes app whereby the delete icon pops up when any list view item is long pressed. Every list view item has a check box which is from my list view component. But i have a checkbox on my toolbar which should automatically check all checkboxes on my list view in case the user wants to delete all notes. Thats why i called it universal check box.

Comment: What i want exactly is how to check all of them from the one on my toolbar.

Comment: Yes i know. I already long time know. Now please answer my questions. Especially about scrolling. Give all info i asked for otherwise this will take ages.

Comment: `Thats why i called it universal check box.` Yes. But the question was why you have then yet another one called 'mCheckBox' on your toolbar or whereever.

Answer (score 0):

```
universalCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {         
                        checkAll(isChecked);

       }
   }
);   

     private void checkAll(boolean checked){
               for (int index = 0; index < parent.getChildCount(); ++index) {
                    View nextChild = (listView.getChildAt(index));
                     mCheckBox = nextChild.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mCheckBox.setChecked(checked);
                }

    }
```

Comment: how do i get reference to the parent parameter?

Comment: parent is just a listView reference.see my updated answer

Comment: also, see this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children